# How to read a file line by line with a scanner and use the info?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, filereader

I'm pretty new to java, and I have something to do that is giving me some trouble.
I have to read a file line from line and then make two strings from each line and use them for something. Everything is working great except for the thing when I have to read the lines from the file. Right now I have the following code:

```
public static Estructura Read() throws IOException {
        Estructura list = new Estructura();

        Scanner teclat = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Nom del fitxer: ");
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(teclat.nextLine()));
        teclat.close();
        String s = file.toString();

        while (file.hasNextLine() || s.charAt(14) != '(') {


                                 ...


        file = new Scanner(new File(teclat.nextLine()));
        s = file.toString();
    }
```

The problem is, when I run it and type `2.txt` it brings me this errors: (the file format is correct)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
    at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.findWithinHorizon(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
    at Llenguatges.Llegir(Llenguatges.java:66)
    at Llenguatges.main(Llenguatges.java:10)
```

Line 66 is this one:

```
file = new Scanner(new File(teclat.nextLine()));
```

So, how can I read one line, use it and keep reading it until the second condition in the while happens?
I hope I explained it well, thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you immediately close the `Scanner`, which closes the `System.in`?

Comment: Because I only read from the keyboard once, isn't it how it's supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

You're closing the `Scanner` at `teclat.close()` and then a couple lines down you're trying to read from it.

Comment: If I remove it, when I type the file name nothing happens.

Comment: replace it with teclat.nextLine(); then your input will be processed.

Answer (score 0):

You did

```
Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(teclat.nextLine()));
teclat.close();
```

and then later

```
file = new Scanner(new File(teclat.nextLine()));
s = file.toString();
```

Since you already closed Scanner named "file", you can't re-read it from Scanner.
If you need input value you took for first teclat.nextLine(), save it somewhere for later use. So it's like

```
File f = new File(teclat.nextLine());
Scanner file = new Scanner(f);
teclat.close();

//blabla

s = file.toString() // or file.getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

As the answer from @Henrik states, you are closing your `teclat` `Scanner` at line 66. Either you only need to process one file, and you should remove the two lines 66 and 67, or you want to process other files by inputting a filename again, and therefore you need to enclose most of your code inside another `while`.

```
public static Estructura Read() throws IOException {
    Estructura list = new Estructura();

    Scanner teclat = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (__SomeConditionYouNeedToChooseYourself__) {
        System.out.println("Nom del fitxer: ");
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(teclat.nextLine()));
        String s = file.toString();

        while (file.hasNextLine() || s.charAt(14) != '(') {


                             ...

        file.close();
        }

    }
    teclat.close();
}
```

I am overlooking a few things, up to you to figure, for example you would want a special input string (or just 'return' - this case is not handled, BTW) to decide to stop, instead of creating the new file...